# Justification for this theoretical experiment to measure temperature change during Joule expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am reading the book *Heat and Thermodynamics* 7th Edition by Zemansky and Dittman.

There is a section of a chapter that I would like to understand (Ch. 5.3).

I'm going to go through the reasoning, paraphrasing some parts and quoting others.

> Imagine a thermally insulated vessel with rigid walls, divided into
> two compartments by a partition. Suppose that there is a gas in one
> compartment and that the other contains a vacuum. If the partition is
> removed, the gas will undergo what is known as an adiabatic *free
> expansion* in which no work is done and no heat is transferred. From
> the first law, since both $Q$ and $W$ are zero, it follows that *the
> internal energy remains unchanged during a free expansion*.
>
> The question of whether or not the temperature of a gas changes during
> a free expansion and, if it does, of the magnitude of the temperature
> change has engaged the attention of scientists for about a hundred
> years. Starting with Joule in 1843, many attempts have been made to
> measure either the quantity $(\partial T/\partial V)_U$, which is
> called the *Joule coefficient*, or related quantities that are all a
> measure, in one way or another, of the effect of an adiabatic free
> expansion, or as it is often called, *Joule expansion*.

Experiments that try to measure a temperature change during a free expansion are difficult in practice.

> Instead of measuring a temperature change during free expansion for
> which the internal energy is constant, consider measuring a change of
> internal temperature for constant temperature.

The internal energy function of any gas is a function of any two of the coordinates $P,V$, and $T$. We can write

$$dU=\left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right )_V dT +\left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right )_T dV\tag{1}$$

and if no temperature change ($dT=0$) occurs in a free expansion ($dU=0$) then

$$\left (\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right )_T = 0\tag{2}$$

which means that $U$ does not depend on $V$

Similarly,

$$dU=\left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right )_P dT +\left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial P} \right )_T dP\tag{3}$$

and once more we have that if no temperature change ($dT=0$) occurs in a free expansion ($dU=0$) then

$$\left (\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right )_T = 0\tag{4}$$

ie, $U$ does not depend on $P$.

> Then, it is apparent that, if no temperature change takes place in a
> free expansion of a gas, $U$ is independent of $V$ and $P$, and,
> therefore, $U$ *is a function of $T$ only*.
>
> Thus, to determine if the internal energy is a function of
> temperature, one must perform an experiment where the temperature is
> constant and measure whether either $\left (\frac{\partial U}{\partial
>  V}\right )_T$ or $\left (\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right )_T = 0$
> is zero.

**My question**

The reasoning here seems to be that if we can determine that $U$ does not depend on $V$ or $P$ in general (actually, not sure about the use of the term "in general" here; I think actually we would be determining this for a particular level of $T$ and $V$ or $T$ and $P$), then this must mean that in the specific case of an adiabatic free expansion (ie, a Joule expansion) we have from (1) and (3) that

$$0=\left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right )_V dT +0\cdot dV\tag{1a}$$

$$0=\left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right )_P dT +0\cdot dP\tag{3a}$$

Now, assuming this is correct, I am not sure about the justification for $\left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right )_V \neq 0$ or $\left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right )_P \neq 0$, but if we assume this then it means that $dT=0$ in both equations.

Is this reasoning correct?

Note that I have a [follow-up question concerning an actual experiment based on the theoretical analysis above](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/177555/understanding-rossini-and-frandsen-experiment-for-measuring-partial-u-partia).